# What should ExecuteAsync do in an ASPNet Core application?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, background-service

I have an ASP.NET Core 6.0 application which I was running as command line, but now have moved it to run as a service if it is started as one. It works fine, but I had to make a service for it and needed to implement `ExecuteAsync`:

```
builder.Services.AddHostedService<ServicePlaceHolder>();
```

Here is that class:

```
public class ServicePlaceHolder : BackgroundService
{
    protected override async Task ExecuteAsync(CancellationToken stoppingToken)
    {
        Log.Information("Service is starting.");

        stoppingToken.Register(() => Log.Information("Stopping"));

        while (!stoppingToken.IsCancellationRequested)
        {
            await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1), stoppingToken);
        }
    }
}
```

But I really do not know what `ExecuteAsync` should be doing, and don't love this silly infinite loop. What should it do? Can I just await the cancellation?

Comment: Does your application have some sort of logic that should be performed over and over until it's told to stop? The Delay is just there as an example.

Comment: You can use `await Task.Delay(Timeout.InfiniteTimeSpan, stoppingToken);` to await until the token is cancelled. However, as @guni2171 said, there may be no point in doing this unless you're doing something over and over.

Comment: If you don't need a background service, don't create one. But then what purpose does your windows service have? If you just want to do something on start / stop, implement `IHostedService` directly.

Comment: The purpose is to execute that method after your web application has finished initializing. You don't need to run it on an infinite loop or anything. You can just run something and exit the method. I do that with BackgroundService all the time. Keep in mind you can implement `IHostedService` as well, which gives you a Start and Stop.

Comment: Background service is the service which will always run on backend, so it will always run the `ExecuteAsync` method.  What is your scenario?

Comment: @Andy can you please submit this as the answer?  This is an ASPNET core app which I need tb be able to run as either command line or as a service.  So as you suggested, the ExecuteAsync does not need to do anything.  I could just not find any examples of a background service used this way - all examples had the method doing something,